# Thread function defined in header file is giving type cast errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Please have a look at the following code

**Server.h**

```
#pragma once
class Server
{
public:
    Server(void);
    ~Server(void);

    DWORD WINAPI serverThread(LPVOID param);

private:
    SOCKADDR_STORAGE from;
    int retval, fromlen, socket_type;
    char servstr[NI_MAXSERV],hoststr[NI_MAXHOST];
    SOCKET serverSocket, acceptSocket;
};
```

**Server.cpp**

*A small part is displayed here.*

```
Server:Server()
{
//Code

//Passing data to thread
        DWORD threadId;
        HANDLE hdl;

        hdl = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) serverThread,(LPVOID)acceptSocket,0,&threadId);

//Code
}


DWORD WINAPI Server::serverThread(LPVOID param)
{
//code
}
```

This code is generating the error

```
 error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
```

That is from the line

```
hdl = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) serverThread,(LPVOID)acceptSocket,0,&threadId);
```

Why is this? Please help!

Comment: A `DWORD(WINAPI Server::*)(LPVOID)` is not a `DWORD(WINAPI *)(LPVOID)`.

Comment: @chris: OK, so you mean it can't be taken into a header file?

Comment: @JesseGood: No it is not. There are no accepted answers. And there is no header file.

Comment: You have to define the serverThread function as a static function, not as a class member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-static methods have different types than static or global methods. Remember that *non-static* member functions have a *hidden* parameter that is the `this` pointer, so your `serverThread` function in essence has a signature like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI serverThread(Server *this, LPVOID param);
```

So you can see why this doesn't work (and wouldn't work *even* with a cast - weird horribleness would happen).

In order to make it compatible with LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, you need to make it static, since static member functions don't operate on a particular instance of a class and therefore don't need a `this` pointer:

```
static DWORD WINAPI serverThread(LPVOID param);
```

And instead of passing acceptSocket as the lpParameter to CreateThread, pass **this**:

```
hdl = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)serverThread, this,0,&threadId);
```

Inside serverThread you can still access the acceptSocket member through the Server object.

Comment: hmmm... Interesting! Anyway, unwanted static stuff can make issues in the future isn't it? In such a case, I need to define it and intialize it inside the .,cpp and not in .h right?

Comment: @Yohan this is actually pretty common and a perfectly valid use of a static member function. You simply use it as a "shim" to cast the argument that you pass to the thread into a pointer to an instance of the class and then invoke some member function on that pointer. I don't know what you mean by "initialize" since you don't have to initialize functions. Like all member functions, you can either declare it in the header file and define it in a separate `.cpp` file, or you can declare it inside the header file.